# How do you get to the hidden phone settings on Android 5.0

Tags: settings, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I have a Galaxy S4 running lollipop and the old way to get to this menu was `*#*#4636#*#*`. How do you do it in other lollipop devices?

Answer (score 0):

*#0011#*  is the code I used on my S4 VE.
Also, I used the Phone info app - it has a tab that has the Android dial codes.